# Beginnings of Topology: Homeomorphisms

Tags: general-topology, definition

Why is a knot and a circle homeomorphic? The general definition of a homeomorphism requires that you be able to deform each to one another.

Comment: And you can deform a knot to a circle!!! In fact, every loop is homeomorphic to a circle.

Comment: The unique thing that makes knots differents from each other is the $\pi_1(X \setminus K)$ where $K$ is the knot.

Comment: You can, just not in $\Bbb{R^3}$. The initial and final products of the deformation (the knot and the circle) live in $\Bbb{R^3}$, but you think think of it as having to pass through $\Bbb{R^4}$ in order to carry out the deformation.

Comment: @ nick cool way to explain that.

Comment: As several other people have stated, the process of deforming one embedded circle into another without leaving $\Bbb{R^3}$, and with the image at each stage of the deformation still being an embedded circle, is called an ambient isotopy, and a knot is an ambient isotopy class of maps $\Bbb{S}^1\rightarrow \Bbb{R^3}$ (or $\Bbb{S^3}$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing homeomorphism, a bijection that is in both directions continuous, and homotopy, which is a deformation from one form to the other.

In the case of knots, one needs ambient homotopies, and only the trivial knots are, by definition, ambient homotopic to the circle.

---

Added: You can of course deform every simple knot into a circle. However, this most often requires self-intersections, which one wants to exclude in knot theory. That is the reason why "ambient". For a knot deformation one requires that a tube around the knot is also moved along, and that at all stages of the homotopy the parametrization of the tube is, locally as well as globally, injective. No folds and no self-intersections allowed.

Comment: I read this on one site, A circle $S^1$ and a knot $K$ (subsets of $R^3$) are homeomorphic -- even though one cannot be deformed into the other (in $R^3$).

Comment: Yes, simple knots are closed rectifiable curves and thus homeomorphic to a circle. There are knots that have multiple connected components, like the boromean rings.

Comment: correct.  A homeomorphism is much weaker than "can be deformed into the other (in $\mathbb{R}^3$)", which is called an ambient homotopy, as LutzL says.  If two topological objects are homeomorphic, this is true regardless of where they live ( ie. are embedded ), or even if they only abstractly exist.  It might be helpful to think of a homeomorphism as having two properties: 1) a bijection and 2) showing the objects are indistinguishable if you look closely enough.

Comment: @Faraad: You cannot deform a circle into a trefoil knot without encountering self-intersections. Nevertheless, a trefoil knot is homeomorphic to the circle.

Comment: Also, why is the circle one dimensional? And the circle group is given by |z|=1 is the circle group? I though groups have one binary operation that turn two elements into a third. Are we not counting multiplying the components as an operation? Sorry if this is unclear.

Comment: A circle is $ 1 $-dimensional because locally, it looks like a line.

Comment: Are you saying, locally it looks like a curve and we know curves are the same as lines from a topological stand point?

Comment: Yes, precisely. You got it, Faraad!